# Create new file via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I have create new file with custom content. But it not run. (Save file name "CustomerList.hta")

Please help me resolve it.

```
<script language="VBScript">
Dim fso, outFile

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim tfolder, tname, tfile
Const TemporaryFolder = 2
Set tfolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
Set tfile = tfolder.CreateTextFile("Customers.txt")
Set outFile = tfile

outFile.WriteLine "This first line"
outFile.WriteLine "The full path file is: " & tfile
outFile.WriteLine "This is last line"
outFile.Close
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor to:

```
'<script language="VBScript">
Dim fso, outFile

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim tfolder, tname, tfile
Const TemporaryFolder = 2
Set tfolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
'Set tfile = tfolder.CreateTextFile("Customers.txt")
sFSpec = fso.BuildPath(tfolder, "Customers.txt")
WScript.Echo sFSpec
'Set tfile = fso.CreateTextFile("Customers.txt")
Set tfile = fso.CreateTextFile(sFSpec)
Set outFile = tfile

outFile.WriteLine "This first line"
'outFile.WriteLine "The full path file is: " & tfile
outFile.WriteLine "The full path file is: " & sFSpec
outFile.WriteLine "This is last line"
outFile.Close
'</script>
```

output:

```
cscript 46349646.vbs
C:\Users\eh\AppData\Local\Temp\Customers.txt

type C:\Users\eh\AppData\Local\Temp\Customers.txt
This first line
The full path file is: C:\Users\eh\AppData\Local\Temp\Customers.txt
This is last line
```

Use the docs (not wishfull thinking) to determine who can do what.

Comment: Thanks for your script but it not work. I have saved with name .hta file.

Its say "Object Require: WScript"

Comment: save it as a .vbs, and run it from the command line using: "cscript file.vbs"
(without the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

A .HTA file is an HTML Application. Your can create that file with notepad (it`s a text format).
Check [this page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/09672c31-8c85-4018-ad86-57a860238132) for a basic hta structure
A basic sample with scripting can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910725/vbscript-with-hta-frontend)

If you need to create dinamically your .hta file you must generate a text file with hta content (basically it is an HTML page).